# Is the power set of a sample space always a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is the power set of a sample space $\Omega$ always a $\sigma$-algebra no matter what kind of $\Omega$ we are dealing with (i.e. finite, countable, uncountably infinite)?

Comment: *Every* set $\Omega$ (empty, finite, countable infinite, uncountable; just doen't matter) has a powerset. It contains exactly all subsets of $\Omega$. If $A\subseteq\Omega$ then $A^{\complement}:=\Omega-A\subseteq\Omega$. If $A_n\subseteq\Omega$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subseteq\Omega$. Finally $\varnothing\subseteq\Omega$. This is all you need for the powerset to be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $\wp(\Omega)$ is evidently closed under complementation and under countable unions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is in some sense equivalent to asking if power sets are closed under countable unions. They are. (obviously closed under complement)

Comment: Sounds right. But, what if the sample space is uncountably infinite, is it wrong to talk about a power set in this regard?